# RESTful set Pragma and Expires

Tags: java, rest, caching, jersey, jax-rs

How to set `"Pragma" = "no-cache"` and `"Expires" = "0"` using RESTful service?

I have added the following

```
 CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
 cc.setNoCache(true);
 cc.setNoStore(true);
 cc.setMustRevalidate(true);
 cc.setMaxAge(0);
```

The above return the following headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Not sure how to set `"Pragma" = "no-cache"` and `"Expires" = "0"`.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set any arbitrary response headers you like in Jersey by injecting `HttpServletResponse` or by returning a `Response` object.

**HttpServletResponse Example:**

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MyObject getValues(@Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    ...
}
```

**Response Example:**

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getValues() {
        return Response.status(200)
                 .entity(new MyObject())
                 .expires(new Date())
                 .header("Pragma", "no-cache")
                 .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg I have used HttpServletResponse. I would like to know both the approach set the headers, does it make any difference in relation to caching of data in IE? The whole point of setting headers was to prevent from caching of data in IE, however despite adding the headers data is caching in IE 8.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference in caching based on how you set them.  I would dump the raw response and make sure the Cache-Control and Pragma headers are set to what you expect.